# Can Javascript functions from form maker run in regular html

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn Javascript to bypass a lack of function in a form builder I was using.
Rookie question but can someone tell me why this doesn't calculate?
The sum should be Hoursworked*Hourlyrate=Basepay.

```
$(function(){
                $("#Hoursworked").keyup(function(){
                    var Hoursworked = $("#Hoursworked").val();
                    //alert(Hoursworked);
                    var Hourlyrate = $("#Hourlyrate").val();
                    $("#Basepay_").html();
                    $("#Basepay_").html(Hoursworked*Hourlyrate);
                })
```

Comment: What happens? What do you expect to happen? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Adding to @dan1st, is `#Basepay_` an input or element like div/span?

Comment: Are there errors in the browser console? You could try adding a `console.log` for debug purposes.

Comment: What exactly are you getting as the value of ‘ Hoursworked’ and ‘ Hourlyrate‘?

Comment: The values come from these cells in my table

<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><label for="Hourlyrate"><b>Hourly Rate</b></label></div>
<div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number"  placeholder="Enter Hourly Rate" id="Hourlyrate" name="Hourlyrate" required></div>
<div class="divTableCell" id="Basepay_">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>

Answer (score 0):

with val() maybe? Hope it helps

```js
$(function(){
$("#Hoursworked").keyup(function(){
    var Hoursworked = $("#Hoursworked").val();
    //alert(Hoursworked);
    var Hourlyrate = $("#Hourlyrate").val();
    $("#Basepay_").html();
    //alert(Hoursworked*Hourlyrate);
    $("#Basepay").val(Hoursworked*Hourlyrate);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="40" id="Hoursworked"/>
<input type="number"  value="10" id="Hourlyrate"/>
<input type="number"  id="Basepay"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, That make the table look a whole lot better. 
Do you know what's missing in this line with the place holder as "Enter Hours Worked" is in red? (Sorry for the jumble of code but when I press CTR+K it opens a searchbar) 

 <div class="divTableCell"><input type="number" value="40" id="Hoursworked"/> <placeholder="Enter Hours Worked" name="Hoursworked" id="Hoursworked" required></div>

Comment: <div class="divTableCell"><input type="number" value="40" id="Hoursworked" placeholder="Enter Hours Worked" name="Hoursworked" id="Hoursworked" required /></div>

Comment: you are welcome, glad I could help, could you click accept answer if it is working?